# how do you convert dict data type fo json in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
r3={'result':[{'serverId':101, 'serverName':'abc', 'data'[{'percentUsed':10, 'value':1, 'rvalue':20}]},{'serverId':102,'serverName':'eee', 'data'[{'percentUsed':30, 'value':3, 'rvalue':24}]}}

print(type(r3))
dict
```

I need to convert this r3 to json

I have tried this

```
json=json.loads(r3)
```

I get this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

Comment: `res = json.dumps(r3)`

Comment: `loads()` goes the other way

Comment: Regarding the error: it looks like you clobbered the `json` package with a local variable named `json`. If this is the case, change the local variable name.

Comment: And generally, "load" means bring stuff in (e.g., load a program) and "dump" means push stuff out.

Comment: `json=json.loads(r3)` likely worked the first time you tried it, but then you reassigned the `json` variable that held the module to the dictionary that you loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `json#dumps`. With `loads`, it takes a JSON string and tries to convert it to a Python dict (the opposite of what you want). Also, your current assignment is trying to redefine the `json` module. Something like this will work:

```
result = json.dumps(r3)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html